# Developing Azure Function Service Bus Triggers on Mac

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a simple Service Bus trigger and I can develop with it on Windows without any issue. But when I am using the trigger on my Mac I get this error:

```
Put token failed. status-code: 401, status-description: InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature..

Message processing error (Action=Receive, ClientId=MessageReceiver1my-topic/Subscriptions/my-sub, EntityPath=my-topic/Subscriptions/my-sub, Endpoint=my-dev.servicebus.windows.net)
```

The function is the boiler plate Service Bus function:

```cs
namespace MyApp.Functions;

public static class MyFunction
{
    [Function("MyFunction")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("my-topic", "my-sub", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] string mySbMsg,
        FunctionContext context)
    {
        var logger = context.GetLogger("MyFunction");
        logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
        
    }
}
```

I updated my nuget packages to the following:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" />
```

I have copied my `local.settings.json` so that it matches what's on my Windows machine which runs fine.

**UPDATE** After much testing, this only appears to be happening when running from Rider OR Visual Studio. I have the Azure tools installed and all other functions work correctly. If I run `func start` it runs fine.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: That's an odd one.   Do you have the full stack trace available?   My best guess based on the context is that the shared key name or value in your connection string is not correct.  The client was able to establish a connection to Service Bus, but auth is failing.   I've seen this happen when a character gets truncated or quotes are accidentally embedded as a literal.

Comment: I just updated to put a little more info from the console out put that includes the "Message processing error..." line

Comment: I updated my nuget packages to the latest for all the function related items, the only change is that it isn't throwing the error at startup but now throws it if I send something through the service bus or after a period of time

Comment: Actually after much test, I got it to run. what seems to be the issue was I was running it in Rider.

Comment: The Service Bus connection is lazy, so I would expect it to be delayed a bit from startup, as the Functions infrastructure has to start the listeners first.  That this only occurs in Rider would seem to rule out the Service Bus extension which is where my knowledge stops.   I'd suggest opening an issue in the Azure Functions runtime repository (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host) or with Rider to dig into the details.

Comment: @JesseSquire it seems to be happening in Visual Studio on the Mac in addition to Rider. If I run it with just `func start` in the terminal it runs fine.

Comment: That definitely sounds like a bug to me.  I don't know enough about the bindings between the functions host and IDE to offer how to best escalate,  but opening an issue for the Functions team in the runtime repository would likely connect you with someone who would know.

Comment: Rider team here  Opening an issue with Azure Functions seems like the way to go. However, also interested to look into your Rider logs if there might be a clue. Feel free to reach out for this issue via email, maarten.balliauw@